# Facebook uses the http protocol to open my app although https is configured in the app settings

Tags: facebook, http, https

I created a facebook app that runs on a server that must be accessed through https. Otherwise it will redirect to https and the signed_request is lost.

In the app settings all URLs that I can edit are using the https protocol. There is no URLs starting with http:// (without the s) -- except for the canvas page url and I cannot change that value (it is http://facebook.com/myappname).

But when I open a facebook page that has installed my app in unsecure mode (http), then facebook seams to remove that "s" from the configured facebook page URL and calls `http://myappdomain` instead of `https://myappdomain`.

My first question:
Is there anything I can do to tell facebook to not rewrite my configured URL? (Or did I make a mistake somewhere else)

My second question:
I think I could load an empty page if the signed_request is missing and put a javascript code in there window.top.location = https://facebook.com/somewhere. But I don't know this "somewhere"  without the signed request. Is it possible to use apaches mod rewrite to pass a post parameter as get parameter?

Providing a http version of the app is no solution for me (customer requirement).

Answer (score 1):

> I think I could load an empty page if the signed_request is missing and put a javascript code in there window.top.location = `https://facebook.com/somewhere`. But I don't know this "somewhere" without the signed request. Is it possible to use apaches mod rewrite to pass a post parameter as get parameter?

Not that I now … but why don’t you serve that little script via HTTP only? You can access the signed_request inside it, figure out your HTTPS target URL, and redirect there via JavaScript.

> Providing a http version of the app is no solution for me (customer requirement).

This way *only* the redirect itself would be served over HTTP – and once the client is redirected by that, HTTPS is being used, and if you only show your “real” app then, would that meet the customers requirements?

Comment: Thanks. We didn't want to make the redirection on an application level. But maybe we can pass only that request to `http://myappdomain/facebook-app-page` to a tiny script that makes a HTTP-header-redirect to the ssl version and passes the signed_request as GET parameter. But I really would like to read an answer that it is possible to reach my goal without any tricks...